# How to use same Android drawable to all resolutios

Tags: android

I have one big image named **panel_bck.jpg** to use in different resolutions to decrease apk size. The image format is **JPG** and it's size is 1.9MB. I put it to default drawable folder only. But when I set the background in code, the BitmapFactory can't find the image at

> drawable/panel_bck.jpg

and the result is all black background. I tested this case with other images(PNG files, JPG files) and there is no problem with them. Only question is that a limitation exist for the drawable size or what is the problem? How can I solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to assign this image to and how are you setting the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image very big resoulation you will set drawable-xxhdpi directory only.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like yours trying to maka a big image fit into a too small `ImageView` and I fixed my problem by using this line in the layout xml file:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

I don't know if it can ba applied to an activity background though.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 9patch image. You can create 9patch image by using the tool called draw9patch located in sdk/tools. First create a large resolution image and give to draw9patch it will create a 9patch image with extension .9.png  add that image in drawable it will solve you problem.
See following links for detail
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

http://codesignature.com/how-to-design-9-patch-buttons-for-android-using-adobe-photoshop-for-all-pixel-densities-and-states/

Comment: Thank you anyway, I'm aware of 9patch but background image is not convenient for it. It is a city picture that covers all activity background, not a button or something else. And the problem only occurs at very restricted types of devices, not all of them.